# превью gif изображения

Tags: php

здравствуйте, как можно сделать так чтобы гифка проигрывалась при клике, а пока этого не произошло было превью в виде какого то кадра из данного гиф изображения

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но на javascript. Например есть готовый плеер https://github.com/apankrat/gif-player

Comment: не вижу смысла от плагина, вручную создавать превью для каждой картинки и при клике с помощью jquery заменять src примитивный способ. у меня новости сами выводятся и я не могу каждый раз это делать